# AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer plays too fast

Tags: ios, macos, video-toolbox, core-media

So I have put together a sample project https://github.com/liuxuan30/TestH264.git that uses VideoToolBox to have a H264 sample decoder to display a stream file, captured from a camera.

The H264 decoder using VideoToolBox is copied from internet, I didn't write it, when I tried to play my h264 stream file, it plays too fast, comparing to ffmpeg or ffplay, which both played back at a normal speed.

I wanted to ask, how to fix this behaviour? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of this constant `kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately`:

> If this key is present, the sample should be displayed as soon as possible rather than
> according to its presentation timestamp. Use this attachment at run time to request this
> behavior from a display pipeline such as the AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer class.
> This attachment is not written to media files.
> [from Apple documation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/kcmsampleattachmentkey_displayimmediately)

So you have two options of displaying:

1. Display immediately - which is probably good for real-time stream, when you need to display frame as soon as possible
2. Display frames at specific timestamp

> *comparing to ffmpeg or ffplay, which both played back at a normal speed.

**ffplay and ffmpeg probably use timestamp at this point.**

I have same result as you from your test H.264 file, but it's happens because you get all decoded frame at once so decoder is displaying it immediately.

You can watch this video for more information about `VideoToolbox` framework:
[Direct Access to Video Encoding and Decoding](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/513/)